# Bluetooth not working after upgrade to 22.04.1

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

Uhhh - I have a fresh upgraded device here

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[  266.311114] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  266.311150] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[  266.311151] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  266.311155] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  266.311157] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  266.311161] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized

inxi -Fz
System: Kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.4 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine: Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 2449A45 v: ThinkPad W530

lsmod | grep -i blue
bluetooth             704512  4 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
```

I tried several things mentioned elsewhere here in the forum to no avail. Any help highly appreciated -mgw

Answer (score 0):

At first, check the status of bluetooth using

```
systemctl status bluetooth
```

If the output shows bluetooth is active and running or inactive, then try this

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

If Bluetooth still doesn't work,

Try this in the command line and perform a system restart.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
sudo apt install bluez
```

Hope that would fix the issue.

Comment: apologies for the long turn around - unfortunately this didn't help. No change - Ubuntu settings telling there is no adapter despite see initial questions code block....